# Empty batch.edge_index when iterating batch through NeighborLoader from torch_geometric

Tags: pytorch-geometric, mini-batch, gnn

I want to train my Graph NN via mini-batch paradigm. I use torch_geometric lib.
I have following tensor:
`edge_index_train =  tensor([[     0,      1,      1,  ..., 319032, 285656, 471076], [941104, 941105, 941106,  ..., 941282, 941379, 941498]])`

and data:
`data_train = Data(user_nodes=user_nodes_train, item_nodes=item_nodes_train, edge_index=edge_index_train)`

Then I create NeighborLoader:
`input_nodes_train = torch.arange(0, num_users_train).long() train_loader = NeighborLoader(data_train, input_nodes=input_nodes_train, num_neighbors=sizes, batch_size=batch_size, subgraph_type='induced', shuffle=True)`
where `input_nodes_train` contains indices of vertices that must be taken as a basis when generating neighborhoods (these are the vertices that are contained in edge_index_train[0]).

But when I try to iterate through train_loader, using:
`for batch in train_loader: print(batch) break`

I get the batch with empty batch.edge_index:
`Data(edge_index=[2, 0], user_nodes=[32], item_nodes=[6415], n_id=[32], e_id=[0], input_id=[32], batch_size=32)`

What could be the problem and how to fix it?

I tried to revert graph's edges, i.e. swap data.edge_index[0] and data.edge_index[1].